# Not printing elements when value of n is equal to size of linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am doing the program for removing nth element from end of the linked list. But problem is that when my size of lined list is equal to n then it is not returning `head.next`. Where I am doing wrong?

```
 class Main{
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;  
          
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    Node head = null;
     public void addFirst(int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if(head ==null){
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        newnode.next = head;
        head = newnode;        
    }
  
    //print list
    public void PrintLL() {
        Node n = head;
        if(n.next==null){
            System.out.println("NULL");
            return;
        }
        while(n!=null){
            System.out.print(n.data+ " --> ");
            n= n.next;
        }
        
    }
    
    //Find nth node from last

    public Node RemoveNthNode(Node head,int nth){
        if(head.next==null){
            return null;
        }
        int size=0;
        Node curNode=head;
        while(curNode!=null){
            curNode = curNode.next;
            size++;
         }

        if(nth==size){
          return head.next;
        }
         
         Node prevnode = head;
        int i=1;
        while(i<size-nth){
            prevnode=prevnode.next;
            i++;
        }
        prevnode.next = prevnode.next.next;
        return head;
   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ll = new Main();
        ll.addFirst(90);
        ll.addFirst(40);
        ll.addFirst(45);
        
         System.out.println("\n");
      
      ll.RemoveNthNode(ll.head, 3);
        ll.PrintLL();
    }
}
```

I tried the code that I have posted but it is not printing when n equal size of LL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that although your function `RemoveNthNode` returns the head after the removal, the caller (in `main`) ignores the returned value, so that it never sees a change to `head`. The confusion may also be caused by the parameter that has the name `head`, which shadows the `head` property of the class instance.

As it is not intuitive that the caller needs to provide `head` as argument, while you would expect that the method would *know* what the head of the list is, I suggest to make it a void method which doesn't take the `head` argument.

You should also take care of the case where `head` is `null`.

Your `PrintLL` has a problem too: it doesn't print the node when the list has just one node.

Corrected code:

```
    public void PrintLL() {
        Node n = head;
        while(n!=null){
            System.out.print(n.data+ " --> ");
            n= n.next;
        }
        System.out.println("NULL");
    }
    
    public void RemoveNthNode(int nth){
        if(head == null || head.next==null){
            head = null;
            return;
        }
        int size=0;
        Node curNode=head;
        while(curNode!=null) {
            curNode = curNode.next;
            size++;
        }

        if(nth==size){
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
         
        Node prevnode = head;
        int i=1;
        while(i<size-nth){
            prevnode=prevnode.next;
            i++;
        }
        prevnode.next = prevnode.next.next;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ll = new Main();
        ll.addFirst(90);
        ll.addFirst(40);
        ll.addFirst(45);
        
        ll.PrintLL();
      
        ll.RemoveNthNode(3);
        ll.PrintLL();
    }
```

Comment: yes. I got another solution too. we can assign the return value as head . i.e in main method .  `ll.head =ll.RemoveNthNode(ll.head, 3);`  so it will assign node value to the head and then print

Comment: Yes, but this is not very elegant. Like I wrote in my answer, the caller should not have to tell the method what the `head` is, because it surely knows that already. Moreover, it can lead to inconsistencies. For instance, what would `list1.RemoveNthNode(list2.head, 3)` have to do?? It is better to avoid such strange mixup.